# Emoji symbols look different on the keyboard key label and textView

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

I try to create emoji keyboard. I have a problem at one of the testing devices:
Emoji symbols look different on the keyboard key label and textView.

Labels text:

```
int code = key.codes[0];
key.label = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(code));
```

Text commiting:

```
String text = String.valueOf( Character.toChars(code) );
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
ic.beginBatchEdit();
ic.commitText(text, 1);
ic.endBatchEdit();
```

All works fine, but at Samsung-device i have a problem. For example:

I use code 0x1F601 for emoji "grinning face with smiling eyes".

Key.label look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f52db.png

and then i click, in textView i see symblo look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2he0.png

Any solution?

(sorry for links, but i haven't 10 reputation for post image, lol)

Comment: Images are identical.

Comment: Fixed. Now the images appear correctly.

Comment: Saying it fixed is not good way, post the solution which you did and marked it accept

Comment: I fixed image links in question, i have no solution

Answer (score 3):

The Unicode standard defines codepoints for 722 emoji, but does not prescribe any style or appearance. It includes a short description for every emoji. Based on this description, people may create their own images or fonts to display the emoji.

Android's default font (Roboto, as on 4.0+) includes monochrome emoji, Apple has a font with colorful emoji (your second picture), and so on. The appearance just depends on the font that is used to display them.

WhatsApp for Android uses the same colorful emoji that Apple uses.

Your first picture may be the result of another font, or of bitmap images that are used to replace the emoji in that application.

If you want to change the appearance of your emoji, you have at least two ways to do this:

- Use another font, for example a custom font that you are embedding in your application.
- Use `Spannable`s to replace the emoji with tiny bitmap images.

More info: https://github.com/delight-im/Emoji

Comment: "Use another font, for example a custom font that you are embedding in your application." Do you know some way for use another font from keyboard? "Use Spannables to replace the emoji with tiny bitmap images." InputConnection don't support Spannables-strings.

Comment: The `InputConnection` just does the keyboard's communication with the app receiving the text, right? This is not the place where you're changing the font or applying `Spannable`s. Only the application can and should control the appearance of the text in its `EditText` (etc.) that receives the text. For where to change the font of your keyboard labels, I don't know, but that should definitely be possible. Don't you have layout files for your keyboard?

Comment: Yes, i can define the font of keyboard key-label. I try define standart font, and issue repeat. I will try define some specific font.